# vaadin grid inline editor not working

Tags: java, grid, editor, vaadin, inline

can someone please help me im a little bit flustered: 
Im trying to just simply display a vaadin grid with 2 columns an test data an do an inline editing of the data.
But the Editor isn't shown correctly in the browser

```
Grid grid = new Grid();
    grid.setCaption("Double click to edit");
    grid.setSizeFull();

    grid.setEditorEnabled(true);
    grid.setSelectionMode(SelectionMode.NONE);

    grid.addColumn("index", Integer.class).setRenderer(new NumberRenderer("%02d")).setHeaderCaption("##")
            .setExpandRatio(0).setEditable(false).setWidth(50);

    grid.addColumn("name", String.class).setExpandRatio(2);

    Slider progressEditor = new Slider();
    progressEditor.setWidth(100.0f, Unit.PERCENTAGE);
    progressEditor.setMax(150.0);
    progressEditor.setMin(1.0);
    grid.addColumn("progress", Double.class).setRenderer(new ProgressBarRenderer() {
        @Override
        public JsonValue encode(Double value) {
            if (value != null) {
                value = (value - 1) / 149.0;
            }
            return super.encode(value);
        }
    }).setEditorField(progressEditor).setExpandRatio(2);
```

that's just the sample code from the vaadin demo page im using here.
But the output is this:

[image: Browser Vaadin Grid Editor View]

Anyone got the same problem or something similar an can help me out here?

regards 
flo

Comment: From that screenshot it looks like there's something wrong with the [theme](https://vaadin.com/docs/-/part/framework/themes/themes-overview.html), Did you change it? Do you have a custom one?